# CSS Animation with an infinitely rotating cube

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make an animation of a rotating cube in 3D but the problem is i want the animation to not have any delay between rotations and i just cant get it to work, right now the cube rotates but it stops for a second before it starts the next rotating animation.

(apparently i need more explanation to post this so ignore the following  part)

//
I am trying to make an animation of a rotating cube in 3D but the problem is i want the animation to not have any delay between rotations and i just cant get it to work, right now the cube rotates but it stops for a second before it starts the next rotating animation
//

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
          perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: top left;
          perspective-origin: top left;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
/* 
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  } */

  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.front {
  background-color: #d50000;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
          transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  background-color: #aa00ff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
          transform: translateZ(-100px);
}

.left {
  background-color: #304ffe;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
          transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  background-color: #0091ea;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
          transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
          transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #64dd17;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
          transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

.

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="cube">
          <div class="side front"></div>
          <div class="side left"></div>
          <div class="side right"></div>
          <div class="side back"></div>
          <div class="side top"></div>
          <div class="side bottom"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
</body
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

Rotation stops because of the default `animation-timing-function` which by default is `ease`.
So it starts and ends very slowly.
Try to use another value `linear`.
As the word suggests Linear starts and ends linearly.
For more explanation see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp)

**Code snippet**

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: top left;
  perspective-origin: top left;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 4s;/*SPEED*/
  animation-delay: 7s;/*REMOVE IF NEEDED*/
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;/*EDITED HERE*/
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
  /* 
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  } */
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.front {
  background-color: #d50000;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.back {
  background-color: #aa00ff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
}

.left {
  background-color: #304ffe;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.right {
  background-color: #0091ea;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.top {
  background-color: #00bfa5;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #64dd17;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
    <div class="side bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-timing-function: linear;` to the `.cube` code.